# "I'll phone you tonight": why is this not proper?

Tags: progressive-aspect

> (1) I phone her tonight.
>  (2) I’m phoning her tonight.
>  (The
>   Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

(1) and (2) are all possible expressions: (1) as a schedule or plan, (2) could be used in the same objects of (1), "but this is not limited to them: it could be that I have simply formed the intention to phone her (without consulting her or anyone else about the matter)”.

But for this following expression, ‘*I’ll phone you tonight*’, the book says “it’s hardly possible if I'd simply said, casually, *I’ll phone you tonight*.” What reason could be possible for this saying?

> “The progressive is restricted to cases where human agency or
>   intention is involved - hence the anomaly of examples like [ib: ‘The
>   sun is setting at five tomorrow’]. The difference between
>   non-progressive and progressive is fairly clear in pairs like [ii: (1)
>   and (2) above]. The non-progressive suggests a schedule or plan:
>   perhaps I regularly phone her on the first Sunday in the month, or
>   perhaps the call is part of some larger plan or arrangement - it’s
>   hardly possible if I’d simply said, casually, *I’ll phone you tonight*.
>   The progressive [iib: (2) above] could be used in these schedule/plan
>   scenarios, but it is not limited to them: it could be that I have
>   simply formed the intention to phone her (without consulting her or
>   anyone else about the matter) and am waiting till I think she’ll be
>   in.” (CGEL, p.171)

Comment: It's not terribly clear which book says the phrase is incorrect, or even why it feels that way. *Phone* is used here as a synonym for *call*, and none of the uses you have listed is incorrect. (Whether they are common is another matter.)

Comment: Are you saying that you have a book that says "I'll phone you tonight" is improper English??  Apart from the fact that I think most Americans would use "call" instead of "phone" I see nothing wrong with that sentence. Is what you've quoted all they say about it? I don't quite understand what their argument is.

Comment: @Jim, The words in the qoutes are all as what they say.

Comment: Could you let us know what comes immediately before "it's hardly possible &c"? ... That is, what does "it's" refer to?

Comment: I don't think (1) is correct, unless it's a small fragment of a sentence ("When I phone her tonight, I will tell her about the party.") On its own, it has to have a future marker in there: "I will phone her tonight."

Comment: I suspect @Listenever is quoting from a book making the same point as [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ufH1AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA297&dq=%22I%E2%80%99ll+phone+you+tonight%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TtBeUpPCIKWV0QXP-oDgBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%E2%80%99ll%20phone%20you%20tonight%22&f=false). Where the issue being discussed is whether *"I'll do it [tonight]"* constitutes a ***prediction***, ***statement of intent*** or ***promise***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's very clever. I'd say it's The Answer, except I'm not sure whether The Question is one of language or of the Social Contract. I suppose showing up in CGEL puts in our jurisdiction.

Comment: @StoneyB, I've written the whole sentences about the examples at the end of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CGEL claims that

1. the non-progressive *I phone her tonight* “suggests a schedule or plan” and therefore would not be employed (“it’s hardly possible”) if the speaker had only a casual intention of calling: an intention of the sort expressed by *I’ll phone you tonight*.
2. The progressive *I’m phoning her tonight* can, like the non-progressive be employed in the case of a schedule or plan; but unlike the non-progressive it can **also** be used of a casual intention.

I agree with CGEL, and in fact would go farther; the non-progressive does not merely “**suggest** a schedule or plan”, it is (in my US experience) only used of a single event when a schedule or plan is the topic.

> According to my calendar she sees Bob in New York this afternoon ... I phone her tonight ... depending on what we sort out you and Carol work up the numbers overnight and email us ... then we've all got a conference call at 8:00 in the morning. 8:00 our time.

The reason, I suspect, is that a very strong non-habitual context, shared by both parties to the discourse, is required to overcome the ordinary habitual/generic implicature of the non-progressive present construction.